# Why won't BufferedWriter write URL content to text file?

Tags: bufferedwriter

I'm trying to write the text from the URL to a text file in batches of 35 lines, pushing enter to continue to the next batch of 35 lines. If I don't try and write to the file in batches of 35 lines it works great and writes all of the content to the text file. But when I try and use the if statement to print in batches of 35 it won't print to the file unless I push enter around 15 times. And even then it doesn't print everything. I seems like it has something to do with the if statement but I can't figure it out.

```
String urlString = "https://www.gutenberg.org/files/46768/46768-0.txt";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        try(Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            InputStream stream = url.openStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\mattj\\Documents\\JuliusCeasar.txt"));) {

            String line;
            int PAGE_LENGTH = 35;
            int lineCount = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                writer.write(line + "\n");
                lineCount++;
                if (lineCount == PAGE_LENGTH){
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("- - - Press enter to continue - - -");
                    input.nextLine();
                    lineCount = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("We encountered a problem regarding the following URL:\n"
                + urlString + "\nEither no legal protocol could be found or the "
                + "string could not be parsed.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Attempting to open a stream from the following URL:\n"
                + urlString + "\ncaused a problem.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Java, but there's very similar concepts in .NET. I think there's a couple of things to consider here.

`BufferWriter` will not write to the file immediately, it acts - as the name suggests - as a buffer, collecting up write requests over time then doing it in batch. `BufferWriter` has a `flush` method to flush the 'queued' up writes to the file immediately - so I'd do this when you hit your 35 (never flush on every write).

Also, `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` are closable, so ensure to wrap them in a `try` statement to make sure resources are properly unlocked/cleared.